# Email test deferred (mail transport unavailable) with ClamAV

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot, clamav

I'm trying to set up a simple new mail server; when I send a test email to the server the email is getting hung up during delivery (user mapping is found) and the email is never found in /home/user/Maildir/new

Here is my **maillog** after a fresh reboot and test email, there are a few warnings I am unfamiliar with.

Can you please point me in the right direction?

> Oct 25 14:54:57 loki dovecot: master: Dovecot v2.0.9 starting up (core dumps disabled)
>
> Oct 25 14:54:58 loki postfix/postfix-script[1369]: starting the Postfix mail system
>   Oct 25 14:54:58 loki postfix/master[1370]: daemon started -- version 2.6.6, configuration /etc/postfix
>
> Oct 25 14:56:00 loki postfix/tlsmgr[1457]: warning: request to update table btree:/etc/postfix/smtpd_scache in non-postfix directory /etc/postfix
>
> Oct 25 14:56:00 loki postfix/tlsmgr[1457]: warning: redirecting the request to postfix-owned data_directory /var/lib/postfix
>
> Oct 25 14:56:00 loki postfix/smtpd[1455]: connect from mail-ob0-f180.google.com[209.85.214.180]
>
> Oct 25 14:56:01 loki postfix/smtpd[1455]: 1CF5E20A8B: client=mail-ob0-f180.google.com[209.85.214.180]
>
> Oct 25 14:56:01 loki postfix/cleanup[1461]: 1CF5E20A8B: message-id=
>
> Oct 25 14:56:01 loki postfix/qmgr[1379]: 1CF5E20A8B: from=, size=1788, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
>
> Oct 25 14:56:01 loki postfix/qmgr[1379]: warning: connect to transport private/scan: No such file or directory
>
> Oct 25 14:56:01 loki postfix/error[1462]: 1CF5E20A8B: to=, orig_to=, relay=none, delay=0.18, delays=0.15/0.02/0/0.01, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (mail transport unavailable)
>
> Oct 25 14:56:01 loki postfix/smtpd[1455]: disconnect from mail-ob0-f180.google.com[209.85.214.180]

**master.cf** snippets:

```
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
smtps     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING


 scan unix -       -       n       -       16       smtp
   -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200
   -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
   -o disable_dns_lookups=yes 127.0.0.1:10026 inet n       -       n       -       16       smtpd
   -o content_filter=
   -o local_recipient_maps=
   -o relay_recipient_maps=
   -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
   -o smtpd_client_restrictions=
   -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
   -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
   -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
   -o mynetworks_style=host
   -o smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts=127.0.0.0/8
```

Answer (score 3):

Found the problems:

1. There is a whitespace before the `scan unix` line.
2. There should be a linebreak between the `-o disable_dns_lookups=yes` and `127.0.0.1:10026` lines.

Correct format:

```
# Must begin with NO SPACES
scan unix -       -       n       -       16       smtp
   -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200
   -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
   -o disable_dns_lookups=yes

# New Line
127.0.0.1:10026 inet n       -       n       -       16       smtpd
   -o content_filter=
   -o local_recipient_maps=
   -o relay_recipient_maps=
   -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
   -o smtpd_client_restrictions=
   -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
   -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
   -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
   -o mynetworks_style=host
   -o smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts=127.0.0.0/8
```